# Liquibase with Docker unable to create DB Connection (Postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, docker, liquibase

I have the following Docker Compose file which is starting the postgres database and afterwards should execute the liquibase scripts.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  foo-db:
    container_name: foo-db
    image: postgres:latest
    ports: 
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: foo
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: foo
      POSTGRES_DB: data
    volumes:
      - foo_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - foo-network
      
  foo-liquibase:
    container_name: foo-liquibase
    image: foo-registry/foo-liquibase:0.1.0
    networks:
      - foo-network
    depends_on:
      - foo-db

volumes:
  foo_data:

networks:
  foo-network:
```

The Dockerfile for the liquibase image looks as follows:

```
# Use the official Liquibase base image
FROM liquibase/liquibase:latest

# Copy your Liquibase scripts into the image
COPY scripts /liquibase/


ENV LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_CHANGELOG_FILE = /liquibase/changelog.xml
ENV LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_URL = jdbc:postgresql://foo-db:5432/data
ENV LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_USERNAME = foo
ENV LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_PASSWORD = foo


# Define the entry point to run the wrapper script
CMD ["liquibase", "--driver=org.postgresql.Driver", "update"]
```

Unfortunately when the liquibase container starts it throws the following error:

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: Connection could not be created to = jdbc:postgresql://foo-db:5432/data with driver org.postgresql.Driver.  Possibly the wrong driver for the given database URL
```

Are there any other driver shipped with liquibase for postgresql?
Or is the problem somewhere else?

Comment: In the Dockerfile `ENV` lines, the extra spaces around the equals sign ` = ` lead to an alternate syntax, which is why you see the equals sign in the error message.  These settings probably shouldn't be in the Dockerfile at all (`docker inspect` will show the database credentials; you'll have to rebuild the image if you change the password); would moving them to a Compose `environment:` section and double-checking the syntax help?